# Porting C-style socket to CPP class

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++14, networking, wrapper

I am porting the C-style socket to design a simple wrapper around the telnet client in CPP. The telnet protocol is accomplished by using [libtelnet](https://github.com/seanmiddleditch/libtelnet) in C. The C-style code for this wrapper is reviewed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/278512/12649) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/278379/12649) as well.

**I want to follow standard practices** in my CPP code, such as using smart pointers in CPP instead of raw pointers, etc. Therefore, please see my implementation below:

**1. simple_telnet_client.cpp**

```
#include <simple_telnet_client/simple_telnet_client.hpp>

namespace simple_telnet_client {

class NotImplemented : public std::logic_error {
 public:
  NotImplemented() : std::logic_error("Function not yet implemented"){};
};

TelnetClient::TelnetClient(const std::string &serverIP,
                           const std::string &serverPort, 
                           const size_t timeOut,
                           const size_t bufferSize)
    : mBufferSize(bufferSize) {
  // define our buffer
  mBuffer = static_cast<char *>(malloc(sizeof(char) * mBufferSize));

  try {
    // let's make socket
    mSockFd = makeConnection(serverIP, serverPort);
  } catch (const std::runtime_error &error) {
    // throw it to the user
    throw std::runtime_error(error);
  }

  // socket related configuarations
  configureReadWriteFd();
  configureTimeout(timeOut);

  // telnet options
  const telnet_telopt_t telnetOpts[] = {
      {     TELNET_TELOPT_ECHO, TELNET_WONT,   TELNET_DO},
      {    TELNET_TELOPT_TTYPE, TELNET_WILL, TELNET_DONT},
      {TELNET_TELOPT_COMPRESS2, TELNET_WONT,   TELNET_DO},
      {     TELNET_TELOPT_MSSP, TELNET_WONT,   TELNET_DO},
      {                     -1,           0,           0}};

  // initialize telnet box
  mTelnet = telnet_init(telnetOpts, trampoline, 0, this);
}

int TelnetClient::makeConnection(const std::string &serverIP,
                                 const std::string &serverPort) {
  int retVal;
  int sockFd;
  struct addrinfo *addrInfo;
  struct addrinfo addrHints;

  // look up server host
  memset(&addrHints, 0, sizeof(addrHints));
  addrHints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  addrHints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

  if ((retVal = getaddrinfo(serverIP.c_str(), serverPort.c_str(), &addrHints, &addrInfo)) != 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("getaddrinfo() failed for " + serverIP + " with error: " + gai_strerror(retVal));
  }

  // create server socket
  if ((sockFd = socket(addrInfo->ai_family, addrInfo->ai_socktype, addrInfo->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
    throw std::runtime_error("socket() failed: " + std::string(strerror(errno)));
  }

  // connect
  if (connect(sockFd, addrInfo->ai_addr, addrInfo->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
    auto error = std::string(strerror(errno));
    close(sockFd);
    throw std::runtime_error("connect() failed: " + error);
  }

  // free address lookup info
  freeaddrinfo(addrInfo);

  return sockFd;
}

void TelnetClient::trampoline(telnet_t *telnet, 
                              telnet_event_t *event,
                              void *user_data) {
  (void)telnet;  // to get rid of unused parameter warning
  TelnetClient *me = static_cast<TelnetClient *>(user_data);
  me->telnetEvent(event);
}

void TelnetClient::telnetEvent(telnet_event_t *event) {
  switch (event->type) {
    // data received
    case TELNET_EV_DATA:
      mReceivedMsg = std::string(event->data.buffer, event->data.size);
      #if DEBUG_MODE
        std::cout << "response: [" << mReceivedMsg << "]" << std::endl;
      #endif
      break;
    // data must be sent
    case TELNET_EV_SEND:
      sendAll(event->data.buffer, event->data.size);
      break;
    // execute to enable local feature (or receipt)
    case TELNET_EV_DO:
      throw NotImplemented();
    // demand to disable local feature (or receipt)
    case TELNET_EV_DONT:
      throw NotImplemented();
    // respond to TTYPE commands
    case TELNET_EV_TTYPE:
      throw NotImplemented();
    // respond to particular subnegotiations
    case TELNET_EV_SUBNEGOTIATION:
      throw NotImplemented();
    // error
    case TELNET_EV_ERROR:
      throw std::runtime_error("telnet error: " + std::string(event->error.msg));
    default:
      // ignore
      break;
  }
}

int TelnetClient::sendAll(const char *buffer, size_t size) {
  int retVal = -1;  // default value

  // send data
  while (size > 0) {
    retVal = send(mSockFd, buffer, size, 0);
    if (retVal == 0 || errno == EINTR) {
      // try again
      continue;
    } else if (retVal == -1) {
      throw std::runtime_error("send() failed: " + std::string(strerror(errno)));
    }

    // update pointer and size to see if we've got more to send
    buffer += retVal;
    size -= retVal;
  }
  return retVal;
}

void TelnetClient::configureReadWriteFd() {
  // clear the set ahead of time
  FD_ZERO(&mReadFd);
  FD_ZERO(&mWriteFd);

  // add our descriptors to the set
  FD_SET(mSockFd, &mReadFd);
  FD_SET(mSockFd, &mWriteFd);
}

void TelnetClient::configureTimeout(const size_t seconds) {
  mTimeout.tv_sec = seconds;
  mTimeout.tv_usec = 0;
}

void TelnetClient::execute(const std::string &command) {
  int retVal = select(mSockFd + 1, NULL, &mWriteFd, NULL, &mTimeout);

  if (retVal == -1) {
    // error occurred in select()
    throw std::runtime_error("select() failed: " + std::string(strerror(errno)));
  } else if (retVal == 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("timeout occurred");
  } else {
    // send the execute
    if (FD_ISSET(mSockFd, &mWriteFd)) {
      #if DEBUG_MODE
        // print only for debugging
        std::cout << "request: [" << command << "]" << std::endl;
      #endif

      telnet_send(mTelnet, command.c_str(), command.length());
    }
  }
}

std::string TelnetClient::response() {
  // erase previously received msg by setting it to an empty string
  mReceivedMsg.clear();

  int retVal = select(mSockFd + 1, &mReadFd, NULL, NULL, &mTimeout);
  if (retVal == -1) {
    // error occurred in select()
    throw std::runtime_error("select() failed: " + std::string(strerror(errno)));
  } else if (retVal == 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("timeout occurred");
  } else {
    // response the response
    if (FD_ISSET(mSockFd, &mReadFd)) {
      if ((retVal = recv(mSockFd, mBuffer, mBufferSize, 0)) > 0) {
        telnet_recv(mTelnet, mBuffer, retVal);
      } else if (retVal == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("connection has been closed.");
      } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("recv() failed: " + std::string(strerror(errno)));
      }
    }
  }
  return mReceivedMsg;
}

TelnetClient::~TelnetClient() {
  if (mBuffer) {
    free(mBuffer);
    mBuffer = NULL;
  }

  // clean up
  telnet_free(mTelnet);
  close(mSockFd);
}

}  // namespace simple_telnet_client
```

**2. simple_telnet_client.hpp**

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_TELNET_CLIENT__TELNET_CLIENT_HPP_
#define SIMPLE_TELNET_CLIENT__TELNET_CLIENT_HPP_

#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <libtelnet.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

// flag to print requests and responses in the console for debugging purposes
#define DEBUG_MODE true

namespace simple_telnet_client {
class TelnetClient {
 public:
  TelnetClient(const std::string &serverIP, 
               const std::string &serverPort,
               const size_t timeOut = 1, 
               const size_t bufferSize = 2048);

  // execute a command on the server
  void execute(const std::string &command);

  // receive the response from the server
  std::string response();

  ~TelnetClient();

 private:
  int mSockFd;
  const size_t mBufferSize;
  std::string mReceivedMsg;

  fd_set mReadFd;
  fd_set mWriteFd;
  struct timeval mTimeout;

  // todo: use std::unique_ptr?
  telnet_t *mTelnet;

  // todo: how about this?
  char *mBuffer;

  static void trampoline(telnet_t *telnet, 
                        telnet_event_t *event,
                         void *user_data);

  int makeConnection(const std::string &serverIP,
                     const std::string &serverPort);

  void telnetEvent(telnet_event_t *event);

  int sendAll(const char *mBuffer, 
              size_t size);

  void configureTimeout(const size_t seconds);

  void configureReadWriteFd();
};

}  // namespace simple_telnet_client

#endif  // SIMPLE_TELNET_CLIENT__TELNET_CLIENT_HPP_
```

PS: I am using C++14 and GCC 9.4 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Avoid using `malloc()` in C++

There are much better ways to allocate memory in C++ that are simpler and safer. First, in C++ you should use `new` if you really want to do your own memory allocation:

```
mBuffer = new char[mBufferSize];
```

But now you have to remember to `delete` it. Even better is to just use `std::vector` to manage a bunch of bytes for you:

```
class TelnetClient {
    ...
    std::vector<char> mBuffer;
    ...
};

TelnetClient::TelnetClient(const std::string &serverIP,
                           const std::string &serverPort, 
                           const size_t timeOut,
                           const size_t bufferSize)
        : mBuffer(bufferSize) {
    ...
}
```

Now you no longer need to free `mBuffer` yourself.
To receive data into the buffer, you can write:

```
retVal = recv(mSockFd, mBuffer.data(), mBuffer.size(), 0);
```

This also avoids a memory leak in the constructor of `TelnetClient`, as when you `throw` because `makeConnection()` failed, the vector will be automatically cleaned up, but manually allocated memory will not.

## Avoid other C-isms in C++

Since you are using socket functions, your code is going to look a bit like C anyway, but try to avoid coding like C and use more idiomatic C++ code where possible. Instead of `memcpy()` and `memset()`, consider using [`std::copy_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) and [`std::fill_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n). But if you just want to zero-initialize a `struct`, you can write this:

```
struct addrinfo addrHints = {};
```

## Pay attention to the return type of functions

In `response()` you declare `int retVal`. This is the right type to store the return value of `select()`. But later on you reuse `retVal` to store the return value of `recv()`. However, `recv()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`. Due to implicit conversion rules this is legal, but the value returned might not fit in an `int`, which can lead to problems. Always store return values in the correct type.

Consider not reusing variables in this case, and using `auto` to deduce the correct type:

```
auto retVal = select(...);
...
auto received = recv(...);
```

## Overuse of exceptions

Exceptions should be used for exceptional errors. However, network errors are rather common, and particularly the remote end closing the connection is quite normal. So arguably, instead of `throw`ing exceptions, you should `return` error codes in these cases. Consider using [`std::error_code`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code) for this.

Since C++17, you could also consider using [`std::optional<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to return things, and in C++23 we will get [`std::expected<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/expected).

You also wrote some code that doesn't make sense at all, for example:

```
try {
    mSockFd = makeConnection(serverIP, serverPort);
} catch (const std::runtime_error &error) {
    throw std::runtime_error(error);
}
```

Here you catch an exception only to rethrow it immediately. Just don't catch it here, the whole point of exceptions is that they will propagate up the call stack until something can actually handle the error.

As Jack Aidley mentioned, it also helps if you create your own exception types that inherit from the [standard exception types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept). This allows callers to programmatically detect exactly what kind of error happened, without them having to parse the `.what()` text.

## Not all errors are fatal

`select()`, `recv()` and `send()` might return -1 also when there is a recoverable error. In particular, if `errno == EINTR`, you should just try again.

## Write log and error messages to `std::cerr`

Always write log, warning and error messages to `std::cerr`. Consider that the regular output of a program goes to `std::cout`, and if you are redirecting the standard output to a file, then if warnings and errors are written to `std::cout` as well, both get mixed up in the file, which is undesirable.

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

Prefer using [`'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former but also forces the output to be flushed, which is often unnecessary and might impact performance.

## Avoiding unused parameter warnings

In C++ you can omit the name of a function parameter, this will suppress unused parameter warnings:

```
void TelnetClient::trampoline(telnet_t *, 
                              telnet_event_t *event,
                              void *user_data) {
  TelnetClient *me = static_cast<TelnetClient *>(user_data);
  me->telnetEvent(event);
}
```

## `response()` might not return the full response

`response()` only ever calls `recv()` once, so it is perfectly possible to only receive a partial response, but the name of this function suggests that it always receives a complete response.

Either this function should be written to call `recv()` in a loop until the whole response has been received (and deal with all the issues you might have with this, which we already discussed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278512/the-receive-function-for-telnet-client)), or it should just be renamed to `recv()` so it implies it has the same semantics as the POSIX `recv()` function.

Comment: Disagree on the overuse of exceptions. This is a perfectly good use of exceptions. However, if I was calling this class I'd prefer to get custom exceptions that allow different causes to be distinguished (since many can be solved by retrying with a fresh connection) rather than just a std::runtime_exception with a string.

Comment: I'd add that `cerr` should be used for the program to print all its own logging, including progress and/or status reports, whereas `cout` should be used for the actual output the program is meant to produce. For example, a program `add 2 3` would print `5` to `stdout` but might print a log message such as `adding 2 + 3 ...` to `stderr`.

Comment: Thanks for providing many great comments. I have following 3 points: ① Regarding the recoverable error, I plan to use `do { select or recv or send ( ... ); } whie (errno == EINTR);` statement. Correct me, if I am on the wrong track, please. ② Renaming response() to recv() is making the compiler unhappy. It is getting confused with recv() from the socket library. ③ The `telnet_t *mTelnet` pointer is still bothering me. I thought of using `std::unique_ptr` to replace it, but it has to incorporate `telnet_free(mTelnet)` as well. I have a feeling the custom deleter in C++ can help, though.

Comment: ① That might work, but note that `errno` doesn't reset itself automatically. ② You have to write `::recv()` to get the `recv()` function from the global namespace then. ③ You could consider creating a wrapper class for `telnet_t`.

Comment: G. Sliepen: The `new` vs. `vector` for allocation of memory on the heap was totally new to me! Thank you very much for this!